# Generation of certificates when auto-enrolling to clients - AD CS

Tags: certificate, certificate-authority, ad-certificate-services

You can auto-enroll machine certificates in an Active Directory environment by using Microsoft Active Directory Certificate Services.

But how is the generation of the certificates, meant for the clients, done in this matter?

Which of the following two options are true:

1. Client creates a CSR for signing by the AD CS (CA).
2. AD CS generates everything and sends this to the client.

Number one is the most secure, since the private key only exists on the client.

Number two is the least secure since the private key also exists on the AD CS - even though it may be momentarily.

Comment: first option is correct, second option is incorrect.

Comment: @Crypt32

Please "answer my question" so I can mark your answer as correct.

Can you confirm your answer by reference to documentation or anything else? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First option is correct.

In Microsoft ADCS, CA server only signs requests prepared by clients. Clients use client-side API to create private key and CSR (for example, [CertEnroll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374850(v=vs.85).aspx) library) and then invoke [ICertRequest::SubmitRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385054(v=vs.85).aspx) method tosubmit request to CA. When signed, client retrieves issued certificate by calling [ICertRequest::GetCertificate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385046(v=vs.85).aspx) method.

CA do not have access to client private keys. However, there is a possibility when Key Archival is implemented. Client securely transmits its key to CA server and CA uses key recovery agent certificates to encrypt the key in CA database.